# Get unmatched string from regex (Android)

Tags: android, regex

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\\"(.*)\\\".*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("\"Hi there\"! How are you");
if (m.find()) {
    try {
        String iGotMyMatchedString = m.group(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Above code will return me string inside double quotes which is "Hi there".
How can i get the remaininig string "!How are you"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not get the unmatched string, instead you can use a capture group around the second part and access to it by calling the `group(2)` on your matched object:

```
".*\\\"(.*)\\\"(.*)"
```